# Android 8 / LG 6: Add next alarm to lock screen?

Tags: lock-screens

On my previous Nexus 5 (which was running Android 6), the lock screen displayed this: 19:05 ⏰ 7:30 (indicating that it's now 19:05 and the next alarm would be at 7:30).

Now that I'm on Android 8 (on a LG G6), I cannot find any way to display the next alarm on my lockscreen. I've seen some videos about Facewidgets, but that only appears to be for Samsung phones. Even the "Always-on-display" doesn't include the next alarm.

Is there a way for me to do that? I've tried even looking at the Android API to see if I could build my own app to customize the displayed clock (there are functions allowing me to get the next alarm clock). I just can't find a way to manipulate what is displayed on the lock screen.

Any ideas is welcome!